# Monthly realized variance, different number of observations per month

Tags: variance

The monthly realized variance is usually computed as:

$\sum_{i=1}^n (r_i-\bar{r})^2$, where $\bar{r}$ denotes the average return of the month,

or as $\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^2$ (I am not sure which definition is more common).

In any case, with this definition, is there not a problem in that estimates for different months cannot be compared due to a different number of observations per month? If so, how is this usually accounted for?

**Edit:** To clarify: I have *daily* observations, out of which I want to calculate *monthly* estimates of the realized volatility.

Comment: Could you give some context to help readers understand *why* you are comparing monthly variances?  What decisions, actions, or follow-up analyses will be made based on them?

Comment: @whuber I want to compare the results to those of a form of a GARCH model thay uses monthly data. Looking back I could also have estimated that GARCH model with daily data, but that's the idea.

Comment: It might be of particular interest, and value, to understand the nature of any temporal correlation among the $r_i$. Is it safe to assume these values are statistically independent or not?

Comment: @whuber If I understand your question correctly: the $r_i$ are not serial correlated indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r_i$, as you write, denote the daily return. The  monthly RV for month $k$ is

$$R^{(m)}_k = \sum r_i^2.$$

On a yearly basis:
$$R^{(y)}_k = \frac{252}{n_k}\sum r_i^2=\frac{252}{n_k}R^{(m)}_k.$$

A suggestion is to use $\frac{1}{12}R^{(y)}_k$ instead of monthly RV. My motivation is that it simplifies comparison between months.

I assume that the $r_i$'s are preprocessed so that they have mean zero.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Why would the returns have to be standardized for this to work (and should the mean be zero)?

Comment: Sorry, they do not! It was meant as a comment to explain why I used the first of the two definitions you gave. In my case $\bar{r}$ is always zero since i removed the mean of $r$ before doing any calculations.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you take $r_i$ to be the mean returns of the months. But then that means that each monthly estimate will now only differ due to $n_k$: i.e. I will get almost the same estimate for each month.

Comment: I hope that my latest edit clarifies this.

Comment: Missing from this answer is any consideration of the (very great) likelihood that the monthly means will vary, thereby contributing to the estimate of the annual variance.  That indicates this formula will be incorrect.

Comment: Then the definition of realized variance is incorrect ;)